погибель (the same as гибель???)
From РОССІЯ И ЕВРЕИ 1924:

Не большевики погубили Россію, а явились сами слѣдствіемъ ея погибели

What is the difference between гибель and погибель? I think гибель is more common. Maybe погибель is more literary? Is there any difference at all in the meaning?

No difference in the meaning. Погибель is a dated variant of гибель.

On Wordreference there is a thread on nouns with and without по- like селение/поселение - https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/nouns-with-and-without-%D0%BF%D0%BE.3926487/#post-20099728 - and they claim there that nouns can have a verbal aspect. I rather bridle at the notion of nouns with a verbal aspect.

Perhaps some of them can, but this isn"t the case.

I would say that погибель is more old-fashioned and literary. In your example the words have the same meaning.
In literature you can find things like:
Он нашел свою погибель - He met his death.
Он ушел в лес себе на погибель - He left for the woods to find his death.

Here погибель is a bit more specific. Гибель is a somewhat common and routine word. It's used to describe facts of death, like:
Гибель корабля - The loss of a ship

It doesn't have a 'soul' or individuality. The above just states the fact that a ship was lost.
Погибель has the same meaning, but it adds a bit of individuality, a bit of drama to the fact of death. It adds some 'flesh' to the death. And so death becomes not just a routine fact, it gets a 'soul' or individuality. And yes, it's more literary.
To sum up: in general гибель is a normal word. Погибель adds more drama, it's a bit old-fashioned and it's not an everyday word.

Anything can be explained with a 'Russian soul' :)
